# Spring Data Embedded Mongo: 'unknown top level operator: $expr' on server

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

when I run any query containing [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operation against Embedded Mongo I get the following error:

`UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $expr' on server`

The command runs fine against my local instance of mongo.

This is the version of embedded mongo I'm using: `testCompile('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.1.1')`

This is the query for reference:

```
Criteria.where("$expr").ne(Arrays.asList("$val.a", "$val.b"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

`flapdoodle` was downloading a version of Mongodb that didn't have that feature by default.

You can override the default version by specifying the following in your

`src/test/resources/application.properties`

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.6.4
spring.mongodb.embedded.features=SYNC_DELAY,NO_HTTP_INTERFACE_ARG,ONLY_WITH_SSL
```

Comment: For more features: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/2f7f44b2cbce0d4bde635d980d112036c553a586/src/main/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/distribution/Feature.java#L33